# Laptop Hanging During Updating

Tags: windows-7, laptop, updates

I have a HP Probook 6560b Laptop computer running Windows 7 64bit and after a fresh reinstall, I installed various software that my company requires, I then hit **shutdown** to kick off the updating process this revealed 106 Updates to install.

Now it has been hanging on 33 of 106 for over an hour... the reason I am asking this is because I once flattened a Toshiba laptop beyond repair from turning the machine off during its updating but I don't know whether this particular laptop has frozen or is taking a long time to install update 33, it still shows signs of life as in the ellipsis moves at the end of the message to show activity.

Can I go ahead and turn the machine off or wait for the update to "finish"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is turning into a very well documented thing - we seem to be getting this question a lot recently on here!

It should be safe to button and turn off the PC.  when it reboots, if you hit problems you can always use system restore to rollback your PC a day and then have a go at updating.  If you still hit probvlems, look at the following possible solutions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2700567
The above link is to the Microsoft Knowledgebase Article on troubleshooting stalled windows updates.

In the article, 3 methods of fixing the updates are mentioned:

- Method 1: Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter
- Method 2: Perform a System Restore
- Method 3: Perform an in-place upgrade

The Update troubleshooter will be your best bet - this will recycle all the update services and files for you and bring you back to a position where you can start updates again.

Also, it is worth checking the following things:

- System Clock - is it set to the correct time?
- Windows Firewall - Is it disabled or allowing updates through?  I know you say they are downloaded and installing - but it has been noted in the past that a bodged download causes an installer to hang
- Are you running on an admin account?

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be a fix for the windows update window within the OS freezing the scenario in my position is that I have shut down the machine and it shows the blue background and "Please do not power off or unplug your machine Installing update 33 of 106" I fear that it has frozen but I may only be able to hold the power button... but I also have a concern that this could prevent the machine from booting back up again...

Comment: Sorry Nathan.. Speed-reading to try and get this answered before my Lunch is over!  If its been hanging that long and thr hard drive light is not flashing, pull the plug.  Your machine should be able to boot and you can go again. If you have any problems, boot to safe mode (F8) and do a system restore to yesterday.. then you'llbe good to re-run your updates (in smaller batches)

Comment: ahh now the HDD light is flashing...

Comment: in which case, it is still installing - allbeit slowly.  be patient and give it a while longer.  If there is no significant activity, kill it!

Comment: okay I will give it some time thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yeah as you suspected I turned it off and it booted fine

Comment: Thats a relief then :)  If you redo the updates, try and do them in smaller batches.  Sounds stupid and time wasting, i know - but this advice has worked before.

Comment: updated to say its safe to button:)